# Having Trouble with PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I'm having trouble working with a foreach loop in my PHP script. I have retrieved an array of records from a database search and I now want to get the total for one of the fields in the found set of records. Here's my code so far:

```
foreach($result->getRecords() as $record){
    $recordTotal = $record->getField('products_total');
    $salesToday = $salesToday + $recordTotal;         
}
```

If 5 records were found and the value of the 'products_total' field was:

1
2
3
4
5

I want to get the total of these (15) and store that in the $salesToday variable. The $salesToday variable doesn't exist prior to this foreach loop.

Can anyone spot the error in my code? If I echo $salesToday after the loop I get 0 instead of 15.

Comment: Try to do `var_dump($result->getRecords())` (outside your loop) and `var_dump($record->getField('products_total'))` (inside your loop) - so you'll be able to check if all structures are well-formed. Also you should initialize your `$salesToday` before loop

Comment: What is this $record->getField('products_total') ? Can you elaborate further? Maybe that has no value at all, thats why it return to 0.

Comment: Does it work if you set up the $salesToday = 0 before your loop ?

Comment: Thanks @AlmaDo - it turns out it was an issue with my access privileges, which was why it was returning zero. Thanks for helping me locate the problem using var_dump - I hadn't used that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be an issue with my access privileges and not being able to view some of the values from the database record. These posts helped me locate the issue and correct the syntax issue with my loop.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the $salesToday before the loop. Each loop iteration won't remember the value before.
The reason for this is a form of automatic memory management called garbage collection. In it's simplest form, the garbage collector will free up memory that isn't being used anymore.

In this example the $salesToday variable is only declared within the loop so it expects the variable to only ever be used in that loop. Say for example you had another loop surrounding everything you had there. If you declared the variable in the 2nd loop, it would only be available in the 2nd and 3rd loops and not the 1st. The same goes for functions/method, if statements etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check if $recordTotal has values in all the iterations. Maybe is always 0.

```
$recordTotal = 0;
foreach($result->getRecords() as $record){
    $recordTotal = $record->getField('products_total');
    $salesToday += $recordTotal;         
}
```

You can try that code, but is the same code that you are using, with the $recordTotal var initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe initialize the $salesToday variable before the for each loop?

```
$salesToday = 0;
```

EDIT:

```
$salesToday = 0;
foreach($result->getRecords() as $record){
    $salesToday += $record->getField('products_total');         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$salesToday=0;
foreach($result->getRecords() as $record){
    $salesToday += $record->getField('products_total');        
}
echo  'Today sales:'.$salesToday.'<br/>';
```